# django sort object_list by through field

Tags: django, django-models

Say I have the good old person/group/membership relationship

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

and i want a generic view that displays a list of persons belonging to a group (specified in the URL) sorted by the date_joined field of the Membership class. I figured I could just do a view like this

```
def group_list(request, pagina):
    return list_detail.object_list(
        request,
        queryset = Person.objects.filter(group__name = slug),
        template_object_name = 'person',
        extra_context = { 'membership' : Membership.objects.all() }, 

        )
```

And then just access the date_joined in the template via  membership__date_joined but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you actually want to do is to start from the Membership object. This is the only thing that is unique for a particular combination of Person and Group - if you start from the Person, as you are doing, accessing their memberships gives you *all* of them, not the one you want. So:

```
return list_detail.object_list(
    request,
    queryset = Membership.objects.filter(group__name = slug),
    template_object_name = 'membership',
)
```

Now in your template:

```
{% for member in membership %}
    {{ member.person.name }}: {{ member.date_joined }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Actually I've just noticed that this is more or less the same solution as arie's, above, except as I say you can do the filtering in the database, rather than with a list comprehension.

Comment: You are right. I just realized how stupid my second approach was, as the list comprehension is totally uncessary in this case ... members for members ... ts :-)

Comment: FUDGE!It took me forever to wrap my head around this even though its so simple. I think I sorta understand querysets now finally.Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to filter directly on the intermediary model:

```
members = [member.person for member in Membership.objects.filter(group__name=slug).order_by('-date_joined')]
```

Or just `members = Membership.objects.filter(group__name=slug).order_by('-date_joined')`

Then you iterate over this list in your template like this:

```
{% for member in members %}
    {{ member.person.name }} : {{ member.date_joined }}
{% endfor %}
```